# Dissect System Restore snapshots

Tags: system-restore

Is there any way to map the `A000????.???` filenames in the System Volume Information to their original names, *without* restoring them?

The reason I ask is that several files in one user's System Volume Information RP1 were infected by a rootkit. Although they've been removed, I'd like to be able to figure out what they were originally. `A0001253.sys` and `A0001211.sys` are not very helpful names. :)

It happened on two systems, one XP SP2, the other XP SP3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Restore Point Forensics](http://www.stevebunting.org/udpd4n6/forensics/restorepoints.htm), which describes restore points in depth.

In short, 
the renamed files are tracked in the "change.log" file.  Search for the file name of interest (the original extension remains unchanged), and the original path is found before the renamed file-name :

[image]